# Min and max values on livecharts cartesian chart wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, livecharts

I want to force the Y axis to be centered on 0 and I have to ensure that min and max values are the same.

I use the MinValue and MaxValue properties of the Axis but it doesn't work (note that there is usually a binding on those values but i changed them for this post).

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding SelectedLine.Unit}"
                      LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"
                      FontSize="14"
                      MinValue="-390000"
                      MaxValue="390000"
                      Foreground="{StaticResource GeneralForegroundColor}">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator Stroke="LightGray"

                                   StrokeThickness="1">
                        <lvc:Separator.StrokeDashArray>
                            <DoubleCollection>
                                <sys:Double>6</sys:Double>
                            </DoubleCollection>
                        </lvc:Separator.StrokeDashArray>
                    </lvc:Separator>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Axis.Sections>
                    <lvc:AxisSection Value="0" StrokeThickness="1"  Stroke="Black">
                    </lvc:AxisSection>
                </lvc:Axis.Sections>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
```

The max value is not 390000 and I don't know how to do to force it

[Max value not the one i'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xDFN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate min/max when you add values to the chart.
It's best to add corresponding binding sources to your data model.

In case you are adding values dynamically you have to recalculate min/max. An most important, the data model must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the properties `MaxAxisValue` and `MinAxisValue` must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event:

```
class ChartModel
{
  public double MaxAxisValue { get; set; }
  public double MinAxisValue { get; set; }

  public ChartModel()
  {
    var chartValues = new ChartValues<double> { 10, 50, -3, -25 };
    this.MaxAxisValue = chartValues
      .Select(value => Math.Abs(value))
      .Max();
    this.MinAxisValue = this.MaxAxisValue * -1;

    this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
    {
      new ColumnSeries()
      {
        Title = "Series 1",                    
        Values = chartValues
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.DataContext>
    <ChartModel />
  </Grid.DataContext>

  <wpf:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
    <wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
      <wpf:Axis MaxValue="{Binding MaxAxisValue}"
                MinValue="{Binding MinAxisValue}">

        ...

      </wpf:Axis>
    </wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
  </wpf:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

---

### Update

It seems that your problem is related to the separators of the axis or their distribution.

First note that although the distribution is not even, the values of `Axis.MinValue` and `Axis.MaxValue` are still respected by the chart. It's just a visual discrepancy, which is introduced by the interval of the divisions.

By default the interval is calculated automatically. I guess the algorithm takes the decimal position of values into account. If max absolute value is 39, then the interval will be either 10^1 or (10^1)/2. In your case you have 390,000 which uses position 10^5. So the interval is set to either 100,000 or 50,000 depending on the range. The divisions start from the lower border e.g. -390,000. Applying the interval of 100,000 will get the highest possible division, which is lesser than or equal to max value (390,000), of 310,000.
This explains why you get the divisions ranging from -390,000 to 310,000.

To "fix" this, you have to decide the number of steps (or divisions) you want to have and set `Separator.Step` explicitly. `Separator.Step` is set to `0` by default, which enables the automatic interval calculations.

The basic formula would be
*step = value_range / desired_divisions_count*

I find the terminology used by LiveCharts quite irritating. I naturally would call the steps *interval* and the number of divisions *steps*. But apparently the designers had a different perception.

Let's say you want to have 10 divisions or grid lines. You would have to set `Separator.Step="78000"` because *78000 = (390,000 - (-390,000)) / 10*.
This will distribute the divisions evenly, where min/max value will each fall on a division.

```
<wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
  <wpf:Axis MaxValue="390000"
            MinValue="-390000">
    <wpf:Axis.Separator>
      <wpf:Separator Step="78000" />
    </wpf:Axis.Separator>
  </wpf:Axis>
</wpf:CartesianChart.AxisY>
```

Comment: I can do the binding, that is not the issue. The problem is that the min and max are not the one i'm putting in the view part. I linked a picture at the end of the message to show that the max is not 390000 but 310000. The max is not the good one with or without the binding

Comment: I see. Then I misunderstood your initial problem. I will update my answer.

Comment: I've found time to update the answer. Sorry for the waiting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked ! I just had to round the min and max values as they were not numbers that could be divided by the the number 10 (number of steps). And it worked like a charm !