# Live Charts, How do i make the graph to follow the last data updates after changing zoom

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, livecharts

How do i make Live Charts graph to show the last update after changing zoom
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fECsZ.png

Comment: need to update min/Max value eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062229/min-and-max-values-on-livecharts-cartesian-chart-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem after zooming and panning. My way is to let the user reset the zoom and panning when they are done looking at the point they want. I did it in code behind when the reset button is clicked.

```
             private void btn_Reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {    
                      foreach (var XAxis in ConstantChangeCartesianChart.AxisX)                    
                      {
                        XAxis.MinValue = double.NaN;
                        XAxis.SetRange(double.NaN, double.NaN);
                      }
                      foreach (var YAxis in ConstantChangeCartesianChart.AxisX)
                      {
                        YAxis.MinValue = double.NaN;
                        YAxis.SetRange(double.NaN, double.NaN);
                      }
                }
```

This will simply reset all the range and minimum value. Hope this help.